# Docker.io + K8s + Ubuntu 23.04 - kubectl intermittently returns `connection refused`

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, raspberry-pi

I've initialized a 3-node K8s cluster. The hosts are Raspberry Pis 4. My goal is a reliable Kubernetes deployment for my homelab use.

On each of the nodes, I've installed `docker.io`,`iptables` ,`kubelet`, `kubeadm`, & `kubectl`. Since I'm using docker as opposed to `containerd`, I've enabled cgroup support by setting the cgroup driver in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
kube01% cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}%
```

I've `init`'d my cluster and joined the worker nodes successfully, and created my config in ~/.kube/config:

```
kube01% kubectl get nodes          
NAME     STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
kube01   Ready    control-plane   11h   v1.27.3
kube02   Ready    <none>          11h   v1.27.3
kube03   Ready    <none>          11h   v1.27.3
```

**Intermittently when running `kubectl` commands, I'm met with:**

```
kube01% kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server [kube01.ip]:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

In some cases this clears without interaction on my part. In some cases, I seem to have to restart `kubelet`, though it indicates it's running fine:

```
kube01% systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-07-05 09:02:07 PDT; 30min ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
   Main PID: 725 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 15 (limit: 4416)
     Memory: 112.4M
        CPU: 2min 47.315s
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─725 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.c>

Jul 05 09:33:05 kube01 kubelet[725]: I0705 09:33:05.014941     725 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="d01bb7bcb9c0fe9f1633647d>
Jul 05 09:33:05 kube01 kubelet[725]: E0705 09:33:05.015693     725 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"S>
Jul 05 09:33:05 kube01 kubelet[725]: I0705 09:33:05.958592     725 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=7206a59a>
Jul 05 09:33:05 kube01 kubelet[725]: I0705 09:33:05.960240     725 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=761a171d>
Jul 05 09:33:05 kube01 kubelet[725]: I0705 09:33:05.961685     725 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=54993b57>
Jul 05 09:33:05 kube01 kubelet[725]: I0705 09:33:05.963287     725 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=8d7c8723>
Jul 05 09:33:05 kube01 kubelet[725]: I0705 09:33:05.966891     725 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=aa900694>
Jul 05 09:33:06 kube01 kubelet[725]: I0705 09:33:06.017001     725 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="f97bdc8171c54a8e9d9cb62b>
Jul 05 09:33:06 kube01 kubelet[725]: E0705 09:33:06.018166     725 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"S>
Jul 05 09:33:06 kube01 kubelet[725]: E0705 09:33:06.020022     725 event.go:289] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{>
lines 1-23/23 (END)
```

Searching seems to point me to three primary resolutions, all of which I've confirmed have been applied in my case:

1. Disable swap (✅ via `sudo swap off -a` and ensuring no swap configured in `/etc/fstab`
2. Configured `containerd`/`docker` for cgroup support (✅ as above)
3. Ensure `~/.kube/config` is appropriately created and permissioned  (✅ as above)

Been slamming my head into this one for a few days now. Any additional guidance to remove this intermittent error?

---

**[Follow-Up]** Reading through Kubernetes and Docker docs, it seems like Kubernetes fully endorses `containerd` and indicates that `docker.io` is not preferred. Might be able to find some workaround, but elected not to swim upstream. I moved my runtime to `containerd` and it's been reliable for several hours now. I'll follow up with more detail if this stays stable until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent ~8h in this cluster and it's been reliable on this front since moving to `containerd`. As I mentioned, [reading through Docker's docs, this stood out](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-old-versions):

> Uninstall old versions
> Before you can install Docker Engine, you must first make sure that any conflicting packages are uninstalled.
>
> Distro maintainers provide an unofficial distributions of Docker packages in APT. You must uninstall these packages before you can install the official version of Docker Engine.
>
> The unofficial packages to uninstall are:
>
> - docker.io
> - docker-compose
> - docker-doc
> - podman-docker
>
> Moreover, Docker Engine depends on `containerd` and `runc`. Docker Engine bundles these dependencies as one bundle: containerd.io. If you have installed the containerd or runc previously, uninstall them to avoid conflicts with the versions bundled with Docker Engine.

### tl;dr:

Don't use container runtimes other than `containerd`